How is the following not a valid CSS property?
I'm getting an error in dev tools saying that the following is an invalid property. I've tested it in all major browsers, current versions;
font-size: clamp(1.71rem, calc(1.71rem + ((100vw - 1440px) * (6.08rem - 1.71rem) / (3680px))), 6.08rem);
The purpose of this clamp function is to scale a heading between 1440px resolutions, upwards to 5120px resolutions. It  assumes a base font-size of 4.56rem at 3840px, and scales in a linear fashion according to increase or decrease contingent to the monitor's resolution.
Am I misunderstanding something here? It looks pretty straight forward;
Minimum Value (Min): 1.71rem

Preferred Value (Value): calc(1.71rem + ((100vw - 1440px) * (6.08rem - 1.71rem) / (3680px)))

Maximum Value (Max): 6.08rem`

Thank you for you assistance.
Kind regards.

I tried replacing the font-size with a normal value such as 4.56rem, and changes were reflected in my page. Thus I am certain it's not overlooked linking issue.

I've dumped the function into an isolated codepen so I know it's not a specificity issue.

I was expected the font-size for the heading to scale proportionately with the resizing of the view port,. but no dice.



What dev tools? Is it possible that your specific tool does not support the property yet? If the property works, ignore the error.

((100vw - 1440px) * (6.08rem - 1.71rem) / (3680px)) This part doesn't make any sense. You cannot multiply/devide a <length> with another <length>. One of the factor (to be precise, right-hand one) of multiplication or division has to be unitless (2px * 2 is okay but 2px * 2px is not). See calc()
